# jquery selector all must match

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have a form & I'm trying to do validation on required fields.

```
$('[:input][".fld_required"]').each(function () {
     if ($(this).val() != '' || $(this).attr('checked')) {
         $(this).addClass("inputError");
         errors["error"] = "Required field(s) missing";
     }
 });
```

I only want to select an input field & class="fld_required".

I'm getting a javascript error.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: `$("input.fld_required")`. Or you mean `$("input, .fld_required")`?

Comment: Why aren't you using the `required` attribute?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 most likely old browser compatibility.

Comment: They're using JavaScript for checking validation anyways, `input[required]` would be easier IMO.

Comment: rink.attendant.6: Does "required" work on older browsers if using jquery?

Comment: @php99 Yes, since you're using jQuery to do the validation and jQuery 1.x is compatible with older browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your selector

```
$('[:input][".fld_required"]').
```

to

```
$('input.fld_required'). //selects the input fields having classname fld_required
```